# Get User Enrollments for Current Semester via Valence

Tags: php, get, desire2learn, valence

I want to gather a list of courses in which a specific user is enrolled, but for the current semester. All I've found so far is how to get *every* course the user has ever been enrolled in.
Is there something along the lines of:
`/d2l/api/lp/1.0/enrollments/users/(userId)/orgUnits/(semesterId)`
?

If anyone has any advice, I'd greatly appreciate it!!!

Thanks in advance,

-- Valence Newbie

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single specific call which will do what you are looking to do. You are going to have to build some code logic to get what you are looking for.

Are you using a Service account or the current user's account? If you are using the current user's account then the MyEnrollments call (http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-lp-(version)-enrollments-myenrollments-) should work (especially for student accounts).

For a Service Account approach here is a suggestion on how you can solve this task:

1) Retrieve all of the Enrollments for the current user using this call - http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-lp-(version)-enrollments-users-(userId)-orgUnits-

I would recommend filtering the above call by OrgUnitTypeId = Course Offering.

2) For each Course Offering Returned, perform this call - http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-(version)-orgstructure-(orgUnitId)-ancestors-

I would recommend filtering the above call by OrgUnitTypeId = Semester.

Comment: Why don't the APIs expose such a simple request. Not having this endpoint creates so much overhead for Brightspace and your clients when needing to do any kind of filtering on this information.